# restarting a multi tier server architecture

Tags: jboss

My project has 4 servers, 2 on one layer and 2 on another layer. I use a context switch to load balance each layer so it shares requests amongst the two servers. 2 servers lie in the presentation tier side and the other 2 servers lie in the application tier (or we call it the business tier). The presentation tier has a dependency on the application tier. Now, the question I have is if one of the servers in the application tier fails to start but the other three servers start up correctly can you just restart that one application server that failed or do you have to restart all 4 servers? We are using jboss on these servers if that helps with the question. If more info is needed please ask.

Comment: In my experience, you only need to start again the server failed in the application tier (we call it Backend). At least with the few applications we have this issue it is ok to reboot a JBoss on Backend (app tier) if the Frontend (presetation tier) was already started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests and to reiterate what was mention as a comment by alpha yes you can just restart one application tier without the need to restart all of the other servers. I did notice that, I don't know if it's a configuration thing or jboss thing, when you restart the application tier server most transactions tend to hit the other application tier that wasn't restarted. I don't know why this happens but it isn't a problem because the transactions, though minimal, that end up going to the restarted server work fine and after some time the balance does return back to 50-50.